# Qt generated project code finds shared library file but still getting undefined references during build

Tags: c++, qt, shared-libraries, qmake

I was given source code for a third party library for controlling a printer. I built a shared object from that. I was able to successfully use that shared object to run a simple program in C. I tried to integrate it with an existing Qt GUI that I built, but I was getting undefined reference errors. So, I made a new, clean Qt project, but I'm still getting the following errors:

```
/usr/bin/ld: main.o: in function `test_printer(int, char const**)':
/home/user/printer-test/debug/../printer-test/main.cpp:142: undefined reference to `sii_api_open_device(void**, char*)'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/user/printer-test/debug/../printer-test/main.cpp:143: undefined reference to `sii_api_close_device(void*)'
```

The .pro and main.cpp are:

```
printer-test.pro

QT += quick
CONFIG += c++17
HEADERS += sii_api.h
SOURCES += main.cpp
RESOURCES += qml.qrc
TRANSLATIONS += printer-test_en_US.ts

qnx: target.path = /tmp/$${TARGET}/bin
else: unix:!android: target.path = /opt/$${TARGET}/bin
!isEmpty(target.path): INSTALLS += target

# Qt generated the following lines when given my library path
unix:!macx: LIBS += -L$$PWD/printer_lib/ -lsii
INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/printer_lib
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/printer_lib

# I added this one afterward
unix:!macx: LIBS += -lrt
```

```cpp
main.cpp

#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>

#include "sii_api.h" //< Library header

void test_printer(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    SIIAPIHANDLE hSiiApiHandle = nullptr;
    sii_api_open_device( &hSiiApiHandle, const_cast<char *>(argv[2]) );
    sii_api_close_device( hSiiApiHandle );
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    //<Qt setting up the gui and engine>

    const char* args[] = {"", "0", "/dev/ttyUSB0"};

    test_printer(3, args);

    return app.exec();
}
```

The qmake generates a Makefile that looks something like this:

```
<snip>
LIBS = $(SUBLIBS) -L/home/user/printer-test/printer-test/printer_lib/ -lsii -lrt <snip>

printer-test: $(OBJECTS)  
    $(LINK) $(LFLAGS) -o $(TARGET) $(OBJECTS) $(OBJCOMP) $(LIBS)
<snip>
```

I was able to get the library linked with a sample C program given to me by the manufacturer. Here is the Makefile I used for the C program:

```
PROGRAM = sample

all:: 
    gcc $(PROGRAM).c -o $(PROGRAM) -L ./printer_lib -lsii -lrt 

clean::
    rm -f $(PROGRAM) *.o
```

As seen in the sample Makefile, I needed to include the rt library as well. The Makefile did not work unless the rt library was included after the sii library. Still, my Qt program does not link.

Comment: Does it make a difference if you use `LIBS += -L$${PWD}/printer_lib`? Also, are you sure PWD is pointing to where you expect?

Comment: @JarMan Wrapping PWD in braces had no effect. I output PWD and it is what I expect - the path to my root project directory.

Comment: What is in the `BuildDir\Makefile`? Does `LIBS` contain `libsii.a`?

Comment: if there is a slight chance that the path is wrong, you could always try to add the lib through Qt creator, it will generate a correct path. Just right click on your project and select add library (make sure you select `external` as lib type)

Comment: @DmitrySokolov No. LIBS still contains -lsii. It didn't get expanded.

Comment: @Megued That's actually what I did. Qt generated those last 3 lines in the .pro file when I did that.

Comment: [Options for linking](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Link-Options.html) : It makes a difference where in the command you write this option; the linker searches and processes libraries and object files in the order they are specified. Thus, ‘foo.o -lz bar.o’ searches library ‘z’ after file foo.o but before bar.o. If bar.o refers to functions in ‘z’, those functions may not be loaded.

Comment: @DmitrySokolov I did finally get it to link with a simple C program I was given. I posted the Makefile I used, and updated my .pro. I needed to link an extra library for it to work, and the order did matter. I used the same library options in the same order in my .pro, but it is still not linking.

Comment: maybe there other dependencies that the lib needs, could you post what error you get?

Comment: @Megued I updated the question with some real API calls and the errors they generate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trying to compile the sample code as a C++ program instead of a C program gave me the clue I needed.

I needed to include `extern "C"` around the API header.

My Qt program compiles now.